# initializing a vector of vectors of a user defined

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I have this struct

```
struct myStruct {
    int a;
    int b;
    }
```

I want to create a `vector <vector<myStruct> > V` and initialize it to `n` empty vectors of type `vector<myStruct>`

I'm trying to use the the [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)
like this:

```
vector<edge> temp;
vector<vector<edge> > V(n, temp);
```

This code works fine in `main`, but when I have `V` inside a class how can I do that inside the class constructor.

**EDIT:**
when I do it in my class constructor I get the following error:
`no match for call to '(std::vector<std::vector<edge> >) (int&, std::vector<edge>&)'`

the code generating the error is:

```
vector<myStruct> temp;
V(n,  temp); // n is a parameter for the constructor
```

Comment: Use an initializer list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that `temp` is not necessary: your code is identical to

```
vector<vector<edge> > V(n);
```

Now to your main question: When your vector is inside a class, use initializer list if the member is non-static, or initialize the member in the declaration part if it is static.

```
class MyClass {
    vector<vector<edge> > V;
public:
    MyClass(int n) : V(n) {}
};
```

or like this:

```
// In the header
class MyClass {
    static vector<vector<edge> > V;
    ...
};

// In a cpp file; n must be defined for this to work
vector<vector<edge> > MyClass::V(n);
```

Comment: in case I can't use an initializer list ? 
my constructor takes a file, reads data and then need to initialize,
how can I do that ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi If you cannot use initializer list, you can use an assignment inside the constructor's body: `MyClass(int n) {V = vector<vector<edge> >(n); }`

Answer (score 2):

Just omit `temp`. The constructor for the class that `V` is inside should look like:

```
MyClass(size_t n) : V(n) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class A
{
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<myStruct>> _v;
public:
    A() : _v(10) {} // if you just want 10 empty vectors, you don't need to supply the 2nd parameter
    A(std::size_t n) : _v(n) {}
    // ...
};
```

You use initializer lists for this kind of initialization.